# Submitting form - Send variables to another page

Tags: php, jquery, forms, post

I have a form on my page, and when I submit this, it will check the different submitted INPUT fields.

Example, I have this variable:

```
$method = inputFilter($_POST['method']);
```

My question is, when the form is submitted, if the $method is example = 1, will I then send all the posted data, to another page, and retrieve the data there?

Example:
 - Submit form on **form.php**
 - If method is = 1, then send the submitted data to **otherform.php**, and let the form here, autosubmit?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. That code is server-side, so it will run the script (which is at the URL) to which your form directs when it is submitted. That script might regenerate the same HTML page, or a completely different one, or send nothing at all to the browser: it's up to how you write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use javascript to change the action of the form based on a checkbox but you should rather use an if inside your server side script and include form.php or otherform.php to process the form.